# Creating a background made of rectangles with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, multidimensional-array, tkinter-canvas

I've been trying to create a program that would draw me a random picture made of filled rectangles, with tkinter. I had in mind to test it with a collection of grey nuances, for this purpose I made a list with 13 hexadecimal strings that would be randomly call during the drawing, on the tkinter canvas.

I've tried to make a 2d array with two - badly designed - loops and for each pixel creating a rectangle. Problem is that I get, after a fairly long time, a black screen, made of several black rectangles I guess. Maybe my variable that carries the picked color isnt of the right type for tkinter in the color='...' thing.

I put right here the code to make it understable, ***sorry for my english*** ;)

```
root=Tk()

colorlist = ['#000000', '#111111', '#222222', '#333333', '#444444', '#555555', '#666666', '#777777', '#888888', '#999999', '#bfbfbf', '#dedede', '#ffffff']

canevas = Canvas(root, width=1920, height=1080)
canevas.pack()

for i in range(1920):
    for j in range(1080):
        ind = randint(0, 12)
        ccolor = colorlist[ind]
        canevas.create_rectangle(i, j, i+1, j+1, fill=ccolor)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***draw me a random picture***: Read up on [module random - Functions for sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#functions-for-sequences)

Comment: I didn't precise my actual problem : I get a black screen, I guess made of several black rectangles. I'll edit my post to made it clearer. What you sent me could improve my code but I don't think that the problem come from this part which work, I've tried it in console by printing my strings. Maybe tkinter doesn't recognize in the good way the color picked as a string ? Anyway, thanks for your time !!

Comment: I think a rectangle of **one** pixel is not possible

Comment: @stovfl: not true. You can create a one-pixel rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rectangles have an outline which is black by default. If you are trying to create a one-pixel rectangle, you need to set the width of the outline to zero with the `width` option. Otherwise, all you'll see in a one-pixel rectangle is the one-pixel outline.

```
canevas.create_rectangle(i, j, i+1, j+1, fill=ccolor, width=0)
```

By the way, instead of computing an index into your colors, you can use `random.choice`.

```
import random
...
ccolor = random.choice(colorlist)
canevas.create_rectangle(i, j, i+1, j+1, fill=ccolor, width=0)
```

Comment: I completely forgot the outline ! Thank you very much, I'll try this :)